# Python - Tweepy Regex

Tags: python, regex, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy streamer to collect some tweets for certain tags, in this case #python.  The streamer part of the script works fine but where I'm struggling is extracting the information from the output.

Tweepy sample:
{"created_at":"Fri Aug 05 17:27:00 +0000 2016","id":761614496666361857,"id_str":"761614496666361857","text":**"Use different Python version with virtualenv #py                                                                                thon #virtualenv #virtualenvwrapper https://t.co/ecedKrCX0L"**,"source":

From the sample, I want to extract and print the bold text however I can't seem to get this to work properly.  So far I've come up with:

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):
        def on_data(self, data):
                try:
                        pattern = re.compile(r'"text":"(.*?)","')
                        for line in data:
                                        x = pattern.search(data)
                                        f = open('tmp', 'a')
                                        f.write(data)
                                        f.close
                                        return True
                        else:
                                pass

                except BaseException as e:
                        print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
                        return True
```

However this doesn't extract the specifics I'm after and continues to print a full tweepy output.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Smells like JSON. Have you tried the [JSON Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) yet?

Comment: Not yet, that's probably next on the list.  Did try the CSV module without any luck but i'm not 100% if its JSON.  Will investigate further!

Comment: It's 100% JSON, based on the example you gave.

Answer (score 1):

The easisest way if you want to extract the text is with json module.

```
import json
class MyListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
            try:
                    json.loads(data)
                    f = open('tmp', 'a')
                    f.write(data["text"])
                    f.close()
            except BaseException as e:
                    print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
                    return True
```

But if you want to use a regular expression this will be the code:

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
            try:
                    pattern = re.compile(r'"text":"([^",]*)","')
                    for line in data:
                                    x = pattern.search(data)
                                    f = open('tmp', 'a')
                                    f.write(data)
                                    f.close
                                    return True
                    else:
                            pass

            except BaseException as e:
                    print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
                    return True
```